# Where are the main differences between ISKCON and Jiva Institute?

Tags: philosophy, gaudiya-vaishnavism

As far as I know both [ISKCON](http://www.iskcon.org/) and [Jiva Institute](http://www.jiva.org)  are Gaudiya Vaisnavas, but what are the philosophical differences between these two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't many philosophical differences between ISKCON and the Jiva Institute.  They both believe in Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's philosophy of Achintya Bhedabheda.  And Babaji Satyanarayana Dasa, the founder of the Jiva Institute, is a former ISKCON member, as he describes in [this web page](http://www.jiva.org/babajis-sahajiyas-and-apasampradayas/):

> I never made any propaganda against Srila Prabhupada, ISKCON or Gaudiya-Math, either through internet, through writing books, articles, or by speaking. On the contrary, in my books I have honored and recognized Srila Prabhupada as a propagator of Gaudiya Vaishnavism.
>
> I left ISKCON, or rather, was forced to leave about fourteen years ago because of some philosophical differences. Having philosophical differences is common any spiritual organization, and this is certainly also the case in our Gaudiya Vaishnava history. The beauty of Vedic Culture is that one can have differences of opinion and respect simultaneously. In fact, our very philosophy is based on the principle of difference and non-difference simultaneously. For the modern mind this seems absurd, and any difference is taken as disrespect and inimical. I tried to reconcile one of the differences I had with ISKCON in my book, “In Vaikuntha not even the Leaves Fall”, so that ISKCON’s teachings could be in line with the teachings of the Gosvamis, but this was not acceptable to the ISKCON leadership. As a result I was mistreated and my book was banned. Thus I saw no possibility of reconciliation, although that was my heart’s desire.
>
> Even though I was defamed and mistreated, I did not endeavor to harm ISKCON or the Gaudiya Math. I have never stepped into ISKCON territory after my departure from ISKCON to avoid any conflict or confrontation. At the same time, curiously many ISKCON leaders over the years approached me privately for philosophical advice and consultation and used the material they received for their own projects – often without mentioning my name which was blacklisted in ISKCON. I was and I am still open to peaceful dialogue.”

In any case, one prominent philosophical difference they have is that ISKCON believes that Jivas sometimes fall from Vaikuntha into the world of Samsara if they do bad deeds in Vaikuntha, whereas the Jiva Institute believes that Jivas who dwell in Vaikuntha never fall from it.  This difference is discussed in great detail in Babaji Satyanarayana Dasa's book "In Vaikuntha Not Even the Leaves Fall", which you can read [here](http://www.interessantes.at/jiva-tattva/InVaikunthaNotEvenTheLeavesFall108.pdf).

Another thing to note is that ISKCON has a sharply negative view of the Jiva Institute, described in [this editorial](http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/08-13/editorials10510.htm) from the ISKCON publication the Sampradaya Sun.  They put Jiva Institute people in the general category of "Babajis" who have the potential of leading ISKCON novices astray by overly focusing on the romantic Lilas of Krishna in Vrindavan, which can lead the novices to material temptation.  They also characterize Jiva Institute people as "Asampradaya" or lacking a proper Sampradaya.  Which brings me to the final difference, namely a difference in Guru Paramparas.  [Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/introduction) is the ISKCON Guru Parampara:

> 1. Kṛṣṇa
> 2. Brahmā
> 3. Nārada
> 4. Vyāsa
> 5. Madhva
> 6. Padmanābha
> 7. Nṛhari
> 8. Mādhava
> 9. Akṣobhya
> 10. Jaya Tīrtha
> 11. Jñānasindhu
> 12. Dayānidhi
> 13. Vidyānidhi
> 14. Rājendra
> 15. Jayadharma
> 16. Puruṣottama
> 17. Brahmaṇya Tīrtha
> 18. Vyāsa Tīrtha
> 19. Lakṣmīpati
> 20. Mādhavendra Purī
> 21. Īśvara Purī, (Nityānanda, Advaita)
> 22. Lord Caitanya
> 23. Rūpa, (Svarūpa, Sanātana)
> 24. Raghunātha, Jīva
> 25. Kṛṣṇadāsa
> 26. Narottama
> 27. Viśvanātha
> 28. (Baladeva), Jagannātha
> 29. Bhaktivinoda
> 30. Gaurakiśora
> 31. Bhaktisiddhānta Sarasvatī
> 32. A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupāda

And [here](http://www.sriharidasniwas.org/index.php/sri-guru-parampara/our-guru-shishya-parampara.html) is the Jiva Institute Guru Parampara:

[image]

Both ISKCON and the Jiva Institute trace their Guru Paramparas to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, the founder of the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect, but ISKCON's Parampara traces its origins to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's shishya Rupa Goswami, whereas the Jiva Institute's Parampara traces its origins to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's shishya Gadadhara Pandita.  It's also worth noting that the Jiva Institute claims that Rupa Goswami received Diksha from Gadadhara Pandita; see [this web page](http://www.jiva.org/sri-gadadhara-panditas-role-in-the-gaudiya-sampradaya/).

Comment: *ISKCON believes that Jivas sometimes fall from Vaikuntha into the world of Samsara if they do bad deeds in Vaikuntha, whereas the Jiva Institute believes that Jivas who attain Vaikuntha never fall from it.* I'd like to comment just briefly on two points here of what you said. ISKCON devotees or Gaudiyas in their traditional understanding of those matters don't believe that "bad deeds", what you mentioned, is material karma like we see in this material world which bound us to samsara (repeated births and deaths). ...

Comment: ... In Vaikuntha everyone is protected from any influence of his deeds. So there is no karma in some ordinary sense there in Vaikuntha. Another point. *whereas the Jiva Institute believes that Jivas who attain Vaikuntha never fall from it* ISKCON also believes the same thing! It's not that ISKCON believes that when you finally reach Vaikuntha after gone through samsara you will fall again to samsara. ISKCON also believes you will not fall again!

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I edited my answer to reflect your second point.  As to your first point, if not bad deeds, then what kinds of deeds result in falling from Vaikuntha?

Comment: Ok. I will respond later perhaps not today but in a few days I think, in our chat room.

Comment: The article refers to the "Sampradaya Sun" as an ISKCON publication. The Sampradaya Sun is not an official ISKCON publication... it is a publication from some ISKCON members.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  According to Vedanta Tradition Jivas are Anadi Baddh, this is accepted in all Sampradayas & all lineages of Gaudiya Sampradaya as well. In recent times Srila Prabhupad the founder Acharya of ISKCON used certain Preaching Strategies like Falldown however remain clear of Siddhant in his books. There are multiple opinions in this regard in ISKCON.

Answer (score 0):

Both are Gaudiya Vaishnavas & both belong to Different lineage within the Gaudiya Tradition. Overall phikosphy is same however certain differences are like:-

1. Jiva Institute Disagrees with the ISKCON Concept of Bhagvata Parampara introduced of Srila Bhaktisiddhant Sarasvati Thakur Prabhupad (Guru of Srila Prabhupad)
2. There is disgareememts on the topic of Varnashram
3. Some sort of difference must be there with the topic of Siddha Pranali & Wearing of Safron cloth.

Other than this overall there isn't any difference as such.

ISKCON comes in lineage of Advaita Acharya & Nityananda Prabhu while Jiva Institute is in lineage of Gadadhar Pandit.